# Why this calculation true? (solution added)

Tags: probability, density-function

Given the following density function $$
f_{(X, Y)}(x, y)=\frac{1}{10} e^{-0.5(y+3-x)}, \quad 5 \leq x \leq 10, \quad y \geq x-3
$$
I am asked to find $P(X<Y)$ but I dont understand the limits of $y$ in the solution:
$$
P(X<Y)=\int_{x=5}^{10} \int_{y=x}^{\infty} 0.1 e^{-0.5(y+3-x)} d y d x=\left.0.1 \int_{x=5}^{10}(-2) e^{-0.5(y+3-x)}\right|_{x} ^{\infty}
$$

why this is not $$
P(X<Y)=\int_{x=5}^{10} \int_{y=x-3}^{\infty} 0.1 e^{-0.5(y+3-x)} d y d x=...$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why this is not...

Because the request is exactly $P(Y>X)$, that is the integral over the domain upper the line $X=Y$

see the picture below

[image]

Comment: So why I have the given $ x-3 \leq y$?

Comment: @Sagigever : I added a drawing to explain. The purple area is the bivariate domain, but the area where $X<Y$ is the one over $X=Y$. If you calculate the integral you thought you have to find 1